# Windows threads: how to signal other threads that a mutex has been released?

Tags: windows, multithreading

I have four threads (in four cores) in Windows, all writing to a single output buffer (at different locations in the buffer).  At some point the buffer will fill up and realloc is called to allocate more memory.  The first thread that finds the buffer full will use a mutex with WaitForSingleObject to gain exclusive access and allocate more memory.  When the realloc is finished, the thread will call ReleaseMutex.

Realloc returns a new handle to the output buffer and a new size.  I need the other threads to be signalled that a realloc has occurred so they can get the new pointer and size before proceeding.

My question is, will WaitForSingleObject or ReleaseMutex signal the other threads that the event has occurred so they can access the new handle and size?  Do I also set an event object (with CreateEvent)?  If not, how would I signal that event?

Comment: all threads need call `WaitForSingleObject` before enter to exclusive region and `ReleaseMutex` on exit. but this is used if you need synchronize threads from different processes. for single process use `EnterCriticalSection / LeaveCriticalSection` or if not need xp support say AcquireSRWLockExclusive / AcquireSRWLockShared, etc

Comment: How does SRWLockExclusive signal that a lock has been acquired and released?  I don't see any signalling mechanism.

Comment: when you need release lock call `ReleaseSRWLockShared` or `ReleaseSRWLockExclusive` - exactly this api signal